# Is there an online emulating screen reader tool to test against a custom web page?

Tags: accessibility, w3c, wai-aria, screen-readers

We are concerned about accessibility on our web site and would like to see how it is perceived and decoded by a common screen reader?

Comment: Then use a screen reader. VoiceOver comes with macOS and iOS, Narrator comes with Windows, TalkBack comes with Android, NVDA is free, JAWS has demo modes.

Comment: There is also https://assistivlabs.com/

Answer (score 34, accepted):

No. At least not one that is any good nor represents how a screen reader actually reads a page or responds to ARIA.

The best answer is to test in real screen readers, ideally by getting real users as they know how to use these tools. Consider contacting your local blind association and see if they offer testing services.

### Screen Readers

Each platform has a screen reader, most are built in. Windows has the most variety.

#### For Windows

- [Use Narrator](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17173/windows-10-hear-text-read-aloud) (it is built in, though not very good right now it is getting much better). Use it with Edge.
- [Download the free NVDA](https://www.nvaccess.org/) screen reader (but please donate to support it). Use it with Firefox
- [Download JAWS](https://www.freedomscientific.com/Downloads/JAWS) and use it in 40 minute increments for free. Use it with IE11.

#### For macOS

- [Use VoiceOver](https://help.apple.com/voiceover/info/guide/10.12/) (it is built in). Use it with Safari.

#### For iOS

- [Use VoiceOver](https://www.apple.com/accessibility/iphone/vision/) (it is built in). Use it with Safari.

#### For Android

- [Use TalkBack](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6283677?hl=en). Use it with Firefox.

#### For Ubuntu

- [Use Orca](https://help.gnome.org/users/orca/stable/).

#### For ChromeOS

- [Use ChromeVox](http://www.chromevox.com/chromeos/getting_started.html) (but only use ChromeVox in this scenario, not as a plug-in for Chrome on Windows or macOS).

### Resources

These are handy to get started with testing on your own. Keyboard shortcuts are necessary to use a screen reader well, beyond just hitting the `Tab` key over and over and over.

- [Basic screen reader commands for accessibility testing](https://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2015/01/basic-screen-reader-commands-for-accessibility-testing/)
- [Screen readers and web browsers – what’s the best pairing for testing?](http://hollier.info/browserpairing/)

Comment: I'm here because of https://twitter.com/scottohara/status/852866736848293888

Comment: What's wrong with the [50+ online accessibility checker tools that the W3 lists](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tools/?q=online-tool)?

Comment: @RubberDuck those aren't screen reader emulators. An accessibility checker can only give a comparison against a spec, and even then it cannot test everything. It can also not account for the different features and quirks of screen readers. This [2012 piece outlines what can and cannot be tested](http://www.karlgroves.com/2012/09/15/accessibility-testing-what-can-be-tested-and-how/) and the author has much more to say on the topic on his site.

Comment: @aardrian you should really include some of that in your answer.

Comment: @RubberDuck The question was about screen reader emulators.

Comment: Echoing @aardrian, testing with real screen readers and real users is essential. I built https://assistivlabs.com to help with that — it's like a Browserstack for screen readers and other ATs — nothing is emulated. But please don't omit testing with real disabled users.

Comment: [Silktide](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/silktide-website-accessib/okcpiimdfkpkjcbihbmhppldhiebhhaf) seems promising, but still looking for something that can be integrated into E2E-tests or similar.

Comment: Silktide emulates low-vision, not screen readers. Still handy for testing but not as a screen reader emulator.

Comment: For e2e tests have listed out screen reader automation tools as of 2023 in https://stackoverflow.com/a/75276390